# Angular Materials - can't get multi items to work

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 8 with Angular Materials to build a multi-level menu. I can get the menu to work by using recursion for each level. I recursively call the same directive that displays each level of the menu.

This all works, and the menu is built as expected. However, the menu does not behave as expected. Examples I have seen, when you hover over an item, the nest item is opened, and if you move off an item, its child is closed.

For example, this is a simple version I made:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-sidenav-multi-level-menu-tvim5b?file=app/app.component.html

**Problem**

My issue is when I build my menu, if I click on an item, the child opens. However, I can never get the child to close unless I click off the menu altogether. It is not behaving like the above example.

**Question**

How can I get my example to be have like the above, and close menu items (children) when the items loses focus?

**Info**

I have not put my specific example in StackBlitz because I don't own the code, and it needs backend services to support the implementation.

I think my issues are because I am building the menu items recursively , and the `[matMenuTriggerFor]` is referencing the menu in the next recursion.

**Code**

sidenav-list.component.html

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <!-- Add the Home item -->
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/home" (click)="onSidenavClose()"><mat-icon>home</mat-icon><span class="nav-caption">Home</span></a>
  <!-- Recurse over the app-sidenav-item -->
  <app-sidenav-item *ngFor="let item of navItems" [item]="item" [depth]="depth+1" [sidenavClose]="sidenavClose"></app-sidenav-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

sidenav-item.component.html `<app-sidenav-item>`

```
<div>
    <button mat-button *ngIf="depth === 1" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"><mat-icon>play_arrow</mat-icon>{{item.name | titlecase}}</button>
    <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="depth > 1" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">{{item.name}}</button>

    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <button *ngIf="item.actions.getItems" mat-menu-item (click)="onItemSelected(item, 0)"><mat-icon>list</mat-icon>Get Items</button>
        <button *ngIf="item.actions.updateItem" mat-menu-item (click)="onItemSelected(item, 1)"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>Update Items</button>
        <button *ngIf="item.actions.addItem" mat-menu-item (click)="onItemSelected(item, 2)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Add Item</button>

        <app-sidenav-item *ngFor="let child of item.children" [item]="child" [depth]="depth+1" [sidenavClose]="sidenavClose"></app-sidenav-item>
    </mat-menu>
</div>
```

**Screen Print**

As you can see, I am able to open more than one item on separate nodes. I cannot get the previous one to close. Also, it only responds to clicks and not mouse hover.

[image]

Comment: I think because you might be doing it dynamically thats why you need to layout the whole menu. the parent when hovered, doesn't trigger close of grandchild until parent or child is different. https://dynamic-sidenav-multi-level-menu-uomjrw.stackblitz.io

Comment: @joyBlanks, thank you for the info.  Yes, I do think it's because I am doing it dynamically (I have to because it is data driven). Also, I am using recursion because then there is no code duplication. But I still don't know if there's a way to fix it?  Or some way to close the children items.

Comment: Is there perhaps some way to change the menu name on each recursion? I have a depth value, maybe I can try that? (was thinking it may be because all the menu names are the same).

Comment: You could try putting them in ngcontainers or ngtemplates and hide them

Comment: @joyBlanks, thanks. What would the syntax in the html look like then?  I am struggling to understand what to change the `#menu="matMenu"` and `[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"` to.

Comment: This example kind of does what I want https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-mat-menu. i.e. `[matMenuTriggerFor]=item.elementRef`.  But I still don't know how to dynamically change the `#menu="matMenu"`.

Comment: This is also doing something similar, but I just can't seem to apply it to my example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393885/angular-matmenutriggerfor-programmatically.

Comment: let me know if the solution posted worked

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the thing, You have to preprocess some data 2 way, that means in your object you have to know if it has children to enable more hierarchy level and you need to know which parent it came from to filter it to build this

and your html should look like this. Since you know you can go 3 - 4 levels you generate template for those levels and play with data when it is there.

There is also another @input for MatMenu called matMenuTriggerData with which the parent will trigger data to child.

```html
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="level1" [matMenuTriggerData]="getData(null, 1)">Animal index</button>


<mat-menu #level1="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-data="data">
      <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data">
          <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="item.children" [matMenuTriggerFor]="level2"
            [matMenuTriggerData]="getData(item, 2)">{{item.label}}</button>
          <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="!item.children">{{item.label}}</button>
        </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>

<mat-menu #level2="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-data="data">
    <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data">
      <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="item.children" [matMenuTriggerFor]="level3"
        [matMenuTriggerData]="getData(item, 3)">{{item.label}}</button>
      <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="!item.children">{{item.label}}</button>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>

<mat-menu #level3="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent let-data="data">
    <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let item of data">{{item.label}}</button>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

Note the last level has no more triggers.

you can write a function for your filtered data

```js
getData(selected, requested) {
  return selected ? {
    data:
      this['level' + requested].filter(item => item.parent === selected.value)
  } : { data: this.level1 };
}
```

Each item will contain `value`, `label`, `parent` and `hasChildren` in different levels, you can directly hook up with api make sure the object is passed has a `data` attribute , see functon getData

You can checkout this solution at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfslub

Hope you can modify to your needs.

Comment: thank you for the answer above. I appreciate the effort.  However, this will not work for me, because my solution is data-driven. This means that it may sometimes be more then 3 levels, sometimes less.

Comment: well do you know the max levels?

Comment: I mean you have to write the code, this is more of the idea

Comment: I don't think it will be large, but I don't know what it will be in the real wold situation. I just want to write this so it can cater for different levels. That's why I chose to use recursion.